# limit number of records returned in sql query

Tags: sql

if "select * from table;" gives the results below,
how can I limit it to only show the 1st 3 records for each ref?

thanks

```
ref other field
----------------------
1234 a
1234 b
1234 c
1234 d
1234 e
5678 a
5678 b
5678 c
5678 d
```

Comment: You'll need to specify what DB you're using. MySQL will have a different answer than Oracle, for example.

Comment: I have same problem for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Microsoft SQL Server 2005+:

```
SELECT ref, OtherField
    FROM (SELECT ref, OtherField, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY OtherField) AS RowNum
              FROM YourTable) t
    WHERE t.RowNum <= 3
```

The same query, using a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx):

```
WITH cteRowNum AS (
    SELECT ref, OtherField, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ref ORDER BY OtherField) AS RowNum
        FROM YourTable
)
SELECT ref, OtherField
    FROM cteRowNum
    WHERE RowNum <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

With Oracle:

```
WITH subquery as 
(
  SELECT ref, row_number() over (partition by ref) rank, other_field
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT ref, other_field from subquery where rank <= 3;
```

Lookup for [Oracle analytic functions](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/analytical/index.html).

Comment: Works as well for PostgreSQL and DB2

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that will work in SQL Server 2005+

```
Select ...
From MyTable As T
    Cross Apply (
                Select TOP 3 T2.OtherField
                From MyTable As T2
                Where T2.ref = T.ref
                Order By T2.OtherField
                ) As Z
```